# Which android unique identifiers requests do not raise privacy concerns?

Tags: android, uniqueidentifier, android-identifiers

I have an app in which I want to create unique identifier per device.
Which properties can I access from the sdk which will not ask special permissions at install time (so it won't raise privacy concerns from users), that can help?
I was thinking imei, android-advertising-id, mac-address, installed-apps, etc.

Comment: Why not generate your own UUID and store that in internal storage? That will distinguish any app install from any other app install. See: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Comment: Where are you trying to store this unique identifier - in a persistent storage, or on the network?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Build.FINGERPRINT because Accessing Build.VERSION.SDK_INT doesn't require any special authorities.

Comment: AFAIK, the `FINGERPRINT` is the same across devices of the same model, as is everything else in `Build`.

Comment: I'm going to ask a question about the FINGERPRINT.